# can I block specific scripts in firefox

Tags: firefox, blocking, adblock, umatrix

with uMatrix I can block domains for specific external content. But I would like to know if there is also a blocker for specific scripts on a domain. With uMatrix it is all or nothing for one source type (image, css, script, ...) for one domain, but I would like to allow some scripts and block other ones on a single domain.

Comment: Use [noscript](https://noscript.net/getit) which is now available for Firefox 57.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I block specific scripts in Firefox?

You can use the latest version of [noscript](https://noscript.net/getit) which now supports Firefox 57:

> Recent development history:
>
> v 10.1.1rc99
>
> - First pure WebExtension release
> - CSP-based first-party script script blocking
> - Active content blocking with DEFAULT, TRUSTED, UNTRUSTED   and CUSTOM (per site) presets
> - Extremely responsive XSS filter leveraging the asynchronous   webRequest  API
> - On-the-fly cross-site requests whitelisting

The [complete list of feature is available here](https://noscript.net/features)